# BuildContex + widget tree

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter

I am following [flutter's documentation about the BuildContext class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html) because it is not clear for me how and why to use this class.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // here, Scaffold.of(context) returns null
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Demo')),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return FlatButton(
            child: Text('BUTTON'),
            onPressed: () {
              // here, Scaffold.of(context) returns the locally created Scaffold
              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text('Hello.')
              ));
            }
          );
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

I do not get this paragraph:

> The BuildContext for a particular widget can change location over time
>   as the widget is moved around the tree. Because of this, values
>   returned from the methods on this class should not be cached beyond
>   the execution of a single synchronous function.
>
> BuildContext objects are actually Element objects. The BuildContext
>   interface is used to discourage direct manipulation of Element
>   objects.

**as the widget is moved around the tree** -> how does this happen?

As per my understanding (and please correct me if I am wrong here) the widget tree is basically how the widgets are "stacked" and how they build each other. Since it is not recommended to have sub-widgets referenced as properties in your CustomWidget class how do I change the position in a tree of a widget returned during the build method (or how does this happen by default because of the framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tree change typically happens when the *build* method conditionally build its descendants

Example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return condition
    ? Foo()
    : Bar(child: Foo());
}
```

With such *build* method, the *BuildContext* of the `Foo` widget changes when `condition` changes.